# Printing out all duplicates key in python dict

Tags: python, csv, dictionary, duplicates

Here is my code

```
with open('book1.csv', 'r') as f:
for key, value in c.items():
    if value == max_value:
        print(key)
        if key in dict_from_csv.keys():
            print(dict_from_csv[key])
```

It prints out only 2 keys but I need all duplicate keys.

this is my CSV it consists of name of projects and costs.
[image]

my full code is

`c = rank(results)`

```
max_value = max(values)

newlist1_value = values
newlist1_value.remove(max(values))

second_max_value = max(newlist1_value)

newlist2_value = newlist1_value
newlist2_value.remove(max(newlist1_value))

third_max_value = max(newlist2_value)

keys = []
mydict = {}

 with open('book1.csv', mode='r') as inp:
    reader = csv.reader(inp)
    dict_from_csv = {rows[2]: rows[3] for rows in reader}
    for key, value in c.items():
    if value == max_value:
        print(key)
        if key in dict_from_csv.keys():
            print(dict_from_csv[key])
```

my goal is to print out all the duplicate names of projects with all the costs.

Comment: Can you share the sample rows of your CSV?

Comment: Perhaps you would like to post a [mre]. That includes valid indentation.

Comment: What are `dict_from_csv`, `c`, and `max_value`?

Comment: @AllanChua added

Comment: @sagi added full code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are creating dict from csv, duplicate keys are overwritten. Use list instead, then keep track of already seen keys in dict. If there are more than 2 values for a given key print them.

```
with open('book1.csv', 'r') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    list_from_csv = [[row[2], row[3]] for row in reader]
    max_value = max([x[1] for x in list_from_csv])
    dic = {}
    res = []

    for li in list_from_csv:
    #iterate over project name and and cost
        key, value = li
        # key is name of project, value is cost
        if value == max_value:
            print('max value', *li)
        if key in dic:
       #check if the project name is already in dic where you store values 
       #for same project name append value to already seen values
            dic[key].append(value)
        if key not in dic:
       # if key is not in dic create new with list of value, so you can append to it later 
            dic[key] = [value]
    # print(dic)

    for key, value in dic.items():
    # finally iterate over stored projects with list of values
    # if there are more than one value , it means it has duplicates so 
    # print them
        if len(value) > 1:
            print(key, *value)
```

Comment: it still didn't print the duplicate.

Comment: if  I got it correcly you want also first value of duplicates. Edited

Comment: Thank you but can you explain how it works because I kind of confused when trying to match the key from different list.

Comment: added comments to code

Comment: May I ask you something. Which line put project name into dic ?

Comment: in this line `dic[key] =[value]` ,  check [how to add to dict](https://careerkarma.com/blog/python-add-to-dictionary/)

Comment: OMG You are the best Thank you @Tomas

Comment: glad it helped, you can upvote or mark as solved

Comment: how to mark as solved ?

Comment: green checkmark near under vote